# Customising the output in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a small problem with SQL.

I have the below SQL output

```
XSTOREATTR_ID    STORE_ID    STRINGVALUE    FLOATVALUE
  0               123          asdf           null
  0               124          awer           null
  1               123          null           20
  1               124          null           30
```

I want the output of my sql to be

```
XSTOREATTR_ID      123        124
  0                asdf       awer
  1                20          30
```

Can someone please help me on the same? I know it can be done in Pivot but I am struggling to get this output.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Elaborate please on the result cos I fail to find a logical patern in the example

Comment: Other than working on the accepance rate, post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution. Also give some test data. You can use [SQL Fiddle online tool](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to provide all this information.

Comment: @JoeGJoseph - Can you please provide suggestions for the questions? Yeah I have accepted few of the answered questions as per your request

Comment: @Jester - If you observe the result, for the xstoreattr_id is 0 and have different string values for different storeids and the same with different float values for xstoreattr_id of 1

Answer (score 0):

DB2 is very limited in what you can do to dynamically set column names:

If you only have a few different values for `STORE_ID`, you can create a hard-coded query:

```
with vals as (
    select xstoreattr_id,
           store_id,
           case when xstoreattri_id = 0
               then stringvalue
               else char(floatvalue)
           end as value
        from table
)
select xstoreattri_id,
       max(case when store_id=123 then value else null end) as 123,
       max(case when store_id=124 then value else null end) as 124
              --and so on...
    from vals
    group by xstoreattr_id
```

This is not very elegant, but it is often useful for quick tasks.

Beyond that, if you want to stick with a pure SQL solution, you need to use [dynamic SQL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000948.html), which consists of making an SQL statement in a character string, then running it.  This is messy.  It is often preferable to use an external programming language to do things like this if possible.

Comment: Hi dan, your query can give me the expected output but there are 1200 xstoreattr ids which i cannot hardcode. Is there any other way for the same?

Comment: @arvind_cool, in that case I'm not sure I really understand your question.  Do you mean that you have 1200 different columns like `STRINGVALUE`,`FLOATVALUE`, etc., in your source table?  Or do you mean 1200 `STORE_ID` values?  In either case, it is really not a great design to have such wide tables.  Maybe if you update your question to explain the problem you are trying to solve, we could help you with a better solution.

Comment: Hi Dan, we have a combination of 1200 different values of STRINGVALUE, FLOATVALUE and INTEGERVALUE columns but the store_id has a combination of around 50 different values.

Comment: @arvind_cool, so you only have one additional column?  You could solve that by adding an additional case in the `case` statement inside the `with(...)` clause.  You would then only need 50 lines in the main select statement, one for each value of `store_id`.